# Can the Killing Curse destroy Horcruxes?

Tags: harry-potter

Close to the end of Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Harry willingly gives himself up to Voldemort. Whilst doing this he is actually giving all of his friends a magic protection. Voldemort partially succeeds in killing Harry, and he is sent to a Limbo state. When Voldemort kills him he also kills his Horcrux. Obviously since Voldemort used the killing curse, it killed Harry and the Horcrux, so why didn't Harry use it on the other Horcruxes? I would have expected that he would at least use it for the greater good, to finish Voldemort.

So does the Killing Curse actually destroy Horcruxes? Why didn't Harry use it when hunting them?

I would like canon answers, as the original question's answers sounded like opinions.

Comment: Note that the referenced duplicate question does not have a selected answer.  No doubt, the author of that question also wanted a definitive cannon based answer.  Asking for a _better_ answer does not change the fact that you've asked the same question.

Comment: A better way to get better answers is to post a bounty

Comment: The reason that that question has no good canon answers is because we don't yet have ANY canon info I'm aware of

Comment: It's a common misconception that Harry's scar (or H.P. himself) is a horcrux for Voldemort because it's some sort of part of Voldemort's mind (or soul). An horcrux is more than that and while the scar of Harry Potter do provide some kind of telepathic link between these two, it does not protect Voldemort from death.  J.K. Rowling has repeated many times in interview that the scar and/or H.P. were not horcruxes.  However, because both the horcruxes and the scar of H.P. are associated with Voldemort and his mind or his soul; it's easy to make a confusion between them.